# Run React and Flask app in one docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker, flask

I'm trying to run my app through docker container using multi-stage build and it doesn't work. Would love any help!
my local project structure is as follows:

```
projDir/
|-- my-app/
| |---- (React files)
|-- Backend/
| |---- (Flask files)
|-- docker-compose.yml
|-- Dockerfile
```

and the dockerfile is:

```bash
# Stage 1: Backend build
FROM python:3.6-alpine as backend
WORKDIR /app/Backend
COPY Backend/ .
COPY Backend/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Stage 2: Frontend build
FROM node:16-alpine as frontend
WORKDIR /app/my-app
COPY my-app/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY my-app/ .
COPY my-app/build my-app/build

# Stage 3: Combine backend and frontend
FROM python:3.6-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=backend /app/Backend /app/Backend
COPY --from=backend /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
COPY --from=frontend /app/my-app /app/my-app

# Make port 5000 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 5000

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run the backend server when the container launches
CMD ["python", "/app/Backend/server.py"]
```

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what problem are you running into?

Comment: the process of the dokerization seems to work but when I open my browser i get an empty page.